# Which programs on Ubuntu support 8 processor cores?

Tags: virtualization, cloud, multi-core

I'm now using the Ubuntu virtual machine through Google Cloud service with 8 processor cores. I want to check if these cores work simultaneously. For doing that I have to run such program which supports multi-core working. Could You recommend some simple program?

Comment: Something like FFmpeg converting with libx264 can use all 8 cores. If this is what you had in mind I can write it up fully as an answer...

Comment: Compile something large with make -j8. All cores will definitely be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great tests is to use FFmpeg for h.264 encoding. I am running an 8 core AMD chip and conky shows that this hits all 8 cores pretty comprehensively.

A sample commandline:

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a copy test.mkv
```

And below is a screenshot using conky to demonstrate all 8 cores running to the max:

[image]

If you are interested I also include the `~/.conkyrc` snippet for the cores:

```
${color grey}${execi 5000 uname -p | cut -c 1-16}
1:  ${cpu cpu1}%  ${cpubar cpu1}  
2:  ${cpu cpu2}%  ${cpubar cpu2} 
3:  ${cpu cpu3}%  ${cpubar cpu3}    
4:  ${cpu cpu4}%  ${cpubar cpu4}  
5:  ${cpu cpu1}%  ${cpubar cpu5}    
6:  ${cpu cpu2}%  ${cpubar cpu6}  
7:  ${cpu cpu3}%  ${cpubar cpu7}    
8:  ${cpu cpu4}%  ${cpubar cpu8}
```